# Rails Haml with inline styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

How would I assign inline styling for a backround-image with a object url in haml? lol.
This is a working version of the div without the object.

```
.main-image{style: "background-image: url('http://example.com/image.jpg');"}
```

But when I try this:

```
.main-image{style: "background-image: url(= @photos[0].image.url);"}
```

It doesn't work out when I add `@photos[0].image.url`,  any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should interpolate this value, instead of writing it directly in your string:

```
.main-image{style: "background-image: url(#{@photos[0].image.url});"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with string interpolation:

```
.main-image{style: "background-image: url(#{@photos[0].image.url});"}
```